# Connect to device in wan network from nested subnetwork with two AVM Fritz!Box routers

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

I have the following network setup:

```
                       Internet

                          ^
                          |
                      WAN |
                +---------+----------+
                |      Router A      |
                |                    |
                |                    |
                |  192.168.178.0/32  |
                |                    |
                |                    |
                +----+-------+-------+
                     |       |
               +-----+       +--------+
           WAN |                      |
     +---------+----------+           |
     |      Router B      |     +-----+------+
     |                    |     |  Device C  |
     |                    |     |            |
     |    172.16.0.0/32   |     |            |
     |                    |     |            |
     |                    |     +------------+
     +-------+----+-------+
             |    |
       +-----+    +-----+
       |                |
+------+-----+   +------+-----+
|  Device D  |   |  Device E  |
|            |   |            |
|            |   |            |
|            |   |            |
+------------+   +------------+
```

Both of the routers are Fritz!Box from AVM. Is there any way i can reach `Device C` from `Device D` without exposing the whole network of `Router A` to the network of `Router B` or even merging them?

Due to some structural constraints of the building the network is set up in, i can not move `Device C` to the network of `Router B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you considered setting up a port-fowarding mechanism on router B?

1. lets consider that device C has a WEB server listening on port 8080, needed to be reached by device D.
2. You may configure a port-forwarding on your router B: [Fritz-box port forwarding tutorial](https://www.edpnet.be/en/support/installation-and-usage/internet/manage-fritz!box/how-to-set-up-a-port-forwarding-on-a-fritzbox.html) such as it will make the 'http://deviceC:8080' available from the router B IP address.
3. So device D will be able to navigate to 'http://routerB:8080', which will in-fact display the deviceC service.

My explanation may be very bad (and i'm sorry for that), but i'm pretty sure that you will have better explanation of it [here (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Comment: Actually your explanation is the complete opposite of bad and makes me feel totally stupid. Sometimes one is unable to see the most obvious solution, like in this case a simple NAT. I am pretty sure forwarding ports will work for me, thanks man!

Comment: ahah no problem. Good luck for your adminNET. :)

Comment: Well just had a look at the particular router again, unfortunately forwarding ports will open them to the WAN completely, probably not the best solution. Looks like i will need to go with a more professional firewall instead of the shitty consumer router on the long-run. Thanks anyways.

edit// on the other hand it just came to my mind, that the router is behind a CG-NAT, so maybe forwarding ipv4 won't be that big of a security risk.

Comment: Not very understanding your point here. If you make the port forwarding rule, all devices in the deviceD network would be able to reach the Device C 'endpoint'. But this is somethng that you may restrict via a smart firewall rule. The problem with doing a NAT rule, is that 'device D' will need to know the 'device C' IPaddress (and this is something that you don't want (if i understand what you said)

Comment: yeah, nevermind - you are right. problem solved. guess yesterdays day was just too long. everything works now as expected, thanks again.